# openldap Fedora 22 - apple.schema and now for the mount section

Tags: fedora, osx, openldap

Hej there!
how do i make the correct ldif file for mounts ?
i found this old webpage but i get errors trying to create it
i'm useing mac OS X as openldap client and it' not mounting the /home at all

here's the web page
https://www.chriscantwell.co.uk/2009/12/automount-and-ldap-on-mac-osx/

```
dn: cn=automountMap,ou=macosx,dc=example,dc=co,dc=uk
cn: automountMap
objectClass: container
dn: automountMapName=auto_master,dc=example,dc=co,dc=uk
objectClass: top
objectClass: automountMap
automountMapName: auto_master
and a mapping for home directories:
dn: automountMapName=auto_home,dc=example,dc=co,dc=uk
objectClass: top
objectClass: automountMap
automountMapName: auto_home
dn: automountKey=/home,automountMapName=auto_master,dc=example,dc=co,dc=uk
objectClass: top
objectClass: automount
automountKey: /home
automountInformation: auto_home
```

ldap_add: Insufficient access (50)
    additional info: no write access to parent

[image]